# Object not found in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Recently, I've learnt PHP and MySQL. I use phpMyAdmin to create and manage database. My database has a table named GraduateExam with 8 fields id, ParticipantName, MathMark, HistoryMark, PhysicsMark, Literature, English, TotalSum. I use this snippet in PHP to query the database:

```
<body>

<?php $username='admin'; $password='admin'; $database='University';
$connect = mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query='SELECT PaticipantName, 
MathMark, HistoryMark, PhysicsMark, Literature,English,TotalSum FROM GraduateExam';
$result=mysql_query($query, $connect);  
$num=mysql_numrows($result);?>

<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Name</font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Math</font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">History</font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Chemical</font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Literature</font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvitica, sans-serif">English</font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvitica, sans-serif">Total Sum</font>
</td>

</tr>

<?php 
$i=1;
while ($i < $num) {
$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"ParticipantName");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"MathMark");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"HistoryMark");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"PhysicsMark");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"Literature");
$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"English");
$f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"TotalSum");
mysql_close();
?>
<tr>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvitica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f6; ?></font> 
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvitica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f7;?></font>
</td>
</tr>

<?php $i++; } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this!
I added a fetch array and changed some things in your "while"
Hope it works ;)

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>

<?php $username='admin'; $password='admin'; $database='University';
$connect = mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query='SELECT PaticipantName, 
MathMark, HistoryMark, PhysicsMark, Literature,English,TotalSum FROM GraduateExam';
$result=mysql_query($query, $connect);  
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_close();
?>

<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Name</font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Math</font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">History</font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Chemical</font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Literature</font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvitica, sans-serif">English</font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvitica, sans-serif">Total Sum</font>
</td>

</tr>

<?php 
while ($array=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$f1=$array["ParticipantName"]);
$f2=$array["MathMark"];
$f3=$array["HistoryMark"];
$f4=$array["PhysicsMark"];
$f5=$array["Literature"];
$f6=$array["English"];
$f7=$array["TotalSum"];
?>
<tr>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font>
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvitica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f6; ?></font> 
</td>

<td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvitica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f7;?></font>
</td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mind you, I'm still fairly new to it myself. But there is one thing I would check. Take a look at the following line:

```
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
```

Try changing it to include your connection information. In your case:

```
@mysql_select_db($database, $connect) or die("Unable to select database");
```

Not sure if that will fix your problem, but hopefully it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Never suppress error messages, even if they're depreciation notices & i'd highly recommend avoiding the use of `or die();`. Instead, throw a notice to be caught by an error handler